# Row-wise concatenation of hundreds of csv files into single dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have hundreds of csv files - each corresponding to a unique chemical. All the csv files have the same format (of 3 columns and values within the columns for each chemical).

I would like to combine all these files via a row-wise concatenation into a single pandas dataframe but not have the header columns from each csv file in the final dataframe.  I am using the following Python code but getting an error from the pd.read_csv section -

*"EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file"*

Code follows below.

```
files_path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\Python\RWE_350files_merge\Drugs"
csvfiles=glob.glob(os.path.join(files_path, "*.csv"))

master_df = []  
for file in csvfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0)
    master_df.append(df)

result = pd.concat(master_df, ignore_index=True)
```

I know the csv files are not "empty" as I can concatenate them from the command line successfully - however, this method retains the header columns from each csv file into the final "concatenated" dataframe - so this is not really acceptable.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried any thing to solve this issue?

Comment: I agree with @Hackaholic. Is this a 'can you help me', or a 'can you do this for me'?
In case you don't know at all ... Try to load _one_ csv file to pandas, then use this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html, and then write some loops and fors and giggles around it, then store the resulting DataFrame back to csv with pandas.

Comment: Just read all the csvs and store the dataframes in a list `df_list`, then you can just do `df = pd.concat(df_list)` (assuming you really have the same columns everywhere).

Comment: Show us the code you are currently working on.

Comment: updated question with code I am working on/with (unsuccessfully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
```

But apparently some of your input files are empty.
Adding in a `print(file)` debug statement
would help you to focus on particular ones that are empty.

You could Look Before You Leap:

```
    threshold = 2
    if os.path.getsize(file) > threshold:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
        master_df.append(df)
```

Or you could decide that it is Easier To Ask Forgiveness Than Permission:

```
    try:
        df = pd.read...
    except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:
        print(file, 'was empty. Continuing...')
```

Comment: Thank you @JH! Yes, it appears one of the 350 files is actually empty and that was causing the issue.  Also, appreciate the pointers on how to look before I leap!